# Sending bulk SMS messages from a server: Options?

Tags: mobile, sms, sms-gateway, gateway, kannel

I have a server and seven "groups" of clients that I need to send SMS messages to.  Each "group" contains ~100 cell phone numbers, and should be structured like this:

Message 1 -> Group 1

Message 2 -> Group 2

Etc

Assuming all group members are using verizon, could I just have my server transmit messages to the group members via verizon's sms gateway?

Message 1 could be sent to num1@vtext.com + num2@vtext.com.....num100@vtext.com.
Message 2, same thing, but num101-num200.

Do you see any problems with this?

Could all messages to all groups be sent from a single email address?

Would something like [Kannel](http://www.kannel.org/index.shtml) help me at all?

Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only problem I can see is that Verizon is likely to have a spam limit (as a reference, AT&T's limit is 250 messages per domain per hour). If time isn't an issue, then you should be fine.

Comment: Nice!  Thanks for that.  How would you get that kind of information from other carriers?  I tried calling verizon and nobody could help me.  

Also - are you sure it's per domain, or is there any possibility that it's per email?

Comment: I have to head out for a bit, but this may be handy [link](http://support.e-zekiel.com/templates/System/details.asp?id=31606&fetch=26546).